# How to close Help Browser in RCP4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I implemented Help in RCP 4 using below code [Help Link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=aktion-hip/relations/relations-master/org.elbe.relations/src/org/elbe/relations/handlers/HelpContentHandler.java#). I opened the help as a new browser . But I unable to close this browser when close the main window. How to close help browser automatically in RCP4?

Comment: BaseHelpSystem.shutdown();

shutdown() method stopped the Help Server, did not close the browser. below message is showing in console when calling shutdown() method. INFO:oejs.session:Stop Help Server: Stopped scavenging

Answer (score 0):

Remember the browser that the help system is using:

```java
IBrowser browser = BaseHelpSystem.getHelpBrowser(true);

browser.displayURL(helpURL);
```

and when you are done call

```java
if (browser.isCloseSupported()) {
  browser.close();
}
```

**But** it looks like most external browsers return `false` for `isCloseSupported`

Comment: browser.isCloseSupported() returns false for external browser. So won't call browser.close().

Comment: As far as i can see that is all there is.